# How can I redirect from one url to another using Tuckey URL rewriting?

Tags: http, url, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I've two domain names e.g. `www.1st-domain.com` and `www.2nd-domain.com`
I want to write a Tuckey URL Rewrite rule to redirect any request that goes to `www.1st-domain.com` to `www.2nd-domain.com`

E.g. if someone hits `www.1st-domain.com/sample` it should be redirected to `www.2nd-domain.com/sample`

I'm trying something like:

```
<rule>
        <name>Domain Name Check</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="equal">www.1st-domain.com</condition>
        <from>^(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">http://www.2nd-domain.com$1</to>
    </rule>
```

It is not working. What am I doing wrong? Please guide.

Comment: http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: Yeah, I know the URL of the plugin. I've mentioned that in my title too. Can you elaborate plz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm happy to admit that I made a mistake & the redirection actually works:

```
<rule>
        <name>Domain Name Check</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="equal">www.1st-domain.com</condition>
        <from>^(.*)</from>
        <to type="redirect">http://www.2nd-domain.com$1</to>
    </rule>
```

Comment: In my case I had `<from>(.*)</from>` instead of `<from>^(.*)</from>` (Note the `^`).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me; not sure if you were using version 3 or 4 of urlrewrite; anyhow - looked up the 4.0.3 docs (https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/index.html#configuration) and tweaked your answer a little; this was all that worked for me in the end (tomcat 9.5)

```
<rule>
        <name>Domain Name Check v2</name>
        <condition type="server-name" operator="equal">^(www.1st-domain.com)$</condition>
        <from>^(.*)</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect">https://www.2nd-domain.com$1</to>
    </rule>
```

Note; the main changing is removing the name="host" attribute and replacing it with type="server-name"

Answer (score 0):

or Another way in 4.0
This willbe specific to the particular rule instead of applying to every rule

```
<to qsappend="true"></to>
```